# link_to remote in rails is doing a full 'get' instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm using links like this all over our product:

```
= link_to "Destroy", item_path(@item), method: :delete, remote: true
```

and they all work great... except for one! This one that isn't working is served via ajax, so its life cycle is:

- It's not there
- User clicks a button
- It appears via ajax
- Click the button - it goes to the "item" page instead of running "destroy.js" like all the others do.

The HTML it generates is this:

```
<a href="/items/31" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a>
```

How is it that all the other destroy links work just as intended, but this one served over ajax doesn't? Do I need to call a JS function or something to hook up the click events, if so which one?

Jquery / Jquery_UJS are not being used in this project - I didn't think this would matter though seeing as all the other remote destroy links work.

Comment: jquery-ujs is exactly what turns links with `data-remote` into ajax calls

Comment: Yup, make sure that the `gem 'jquery-rails'` is in your Gemfile and in application.js you have
`//= require  //= require jquery_ujs`

Comment: jquery ujs can't be what turns data remote links into ajax calls because it's working in the rest of the application!

Comment: Well, you were right! it was ujs that caused this but it looks like ujs is only responsible for these links if the links come back over ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Konrad Oleksiuk was right - it was the missing jquery ujs that was the issue.

I was confused about this because it was *mostly* okay - this turned out to be a hack or two my predecessor had done to make mootools "approximately immitate" jquery ujs.